# Win32: Editbox + Multiline + Wrap = Get Text Height?

Tags: winapi, textbox, multiline

I'm trying to stack some read-only textboxes on top of eachother to make a long scrollable list that can be cut and pasted.

So I create a simple textbox with a  huge height....

```
HWND aTextBox=CreateWindow("Edit",theText.c(), WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_READONLY, 10, 10,aWidth-20,9999, aWindow, NULL, NULL, NULL);
SendMessage(aTextBox, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)gTextFont, 0);
```

...And now I want to figure out the height of the text within so that I can resize the textbox's height to fit.
 I'm doing this right now:

```
HDC aHDC=GetDC(aTextBox);
RECT aRect;
DrawText(aHDC,theText.c(),theText.Len(),&aRect,DT_CALCRECT|DT_LEFT);

// Now size the textbox...
SetWindowPos(aTextBox,NULL,0,0,aWidth-20,aRect.bottom-aRect.top,SWP_NOMOVE);
```

I am getting strange results that seem to be close... but not exact.  Some are too large, some are too small, some are spot on.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You also need to select the text box's font into the DC before performing the calculation. ie: `HDC aHDC=GetDC(...); HFONT hOldFont = (HFONT)::SelectObject(aHDC, gTextFont); RECT aRect; DrawText(...); ::SelectObject(aHDC, hOldFont);`